# how to trigger button onmouseup handler from javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

how to trigger onmouseup handler from javascript

i have my button

```
<input id="x" onmouseup="doStuff()">
```

and i want to trigger

```
document.getElementById("x").onmouseup();?????
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've already answered your question :)

Simply call

```
document.getElementById("x").onmouseup()
```

in your code.

I've added an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cUCWn/2/

Comment: Is it possible that onmouseup/down/move() are no more available? In my case it says that it is not a function/

Comment: This still works in the latest version of Firefox using the code `<button onmouseup="console.log('onclick');">TEST</button>`. The error indicates that the function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use event binding there is always this way of doing things

```
document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    alert('triggered');
}, false);​
```

Here is the [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpRjf/) of it.

Or if you want to actually "Trigger the event" try this

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initEvent("mouseup", true, true);
document.getElementById("x").dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about binding the mouseup event of "x" to a function, and then call that function from doStuff?

Answer (score 0):

**You pretty much have the answer there.**

```
<input id="x" onmouseup="doStuff()" />
```

**and then just declare your function**

```
<script type="javascript">
    function doStuff() {
        alert("Yay!");
    }
</script>
```

**Alternatively, you can attach the event from Javascript. i.e.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById("x");
    x.onmouseup = doSomething;

    function doSomething() {
        alert("Yay!");
    }
</script>
```